# Error en la visualización de imágenes en apache consumiéndolas desde un servidor NAS

Tags: apache, ubuntu, imagen, nginx

Buen día,
Estoy obteniendo un error al momento de visualizar las imágenes en apache 2.4.34 consumiéndolas desde un servidos NAS, las imágenes se ven de la siguiente manera 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto mismo lo realizo con un servidor NGINX 1.14.0 y aquí se visualiza la imagen correctamente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El servidor NAS se consume montándolo con el siguiente comando en el archivo /etc/fstab

> //X.X.X.X/vol_XXX/ /mnt/NAS/Aplicativos/ cifs
>   username=username,password=password,domain=domain,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,context="system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0",uid=www-data,gid=www-data
>   0 0

Las especificaciones del Sistema operativo del servidor que contiene tanto apache como NGINX son:

> UBUNTU 18.04.1 LTS version del kernell : 4.15.0-36-generic

** Se monto de la misma manera el servidor NAS en un UBUNTU 16.04 LTS con un kernel 3.19.0-25-generic con apache 2.4.7 y las imágenes se visualizan correctamente

Agradecería mucho su ayuda ya que no encuentro el problema del por que no visualizo correctamente las imágenes.